# Javascript, JQuery toUnicode emoji (Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference)

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoji

I am trying to build a chat with emoji picker.
Ran into some problems with a function i found.
The toUnicode function works fine in Chrome but not internet explorer.

basicly i give the function a unicode and then returns a emoji.
if anyone has an idea how to fix this function to work with internet explorer i would be so happy :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var emojiUnicode = toUnicode('1F600');

    console.log(emojiUnicode);
    $('#test').html(emojiUnicode);

    function toUnicode(code) {
        var codes = code.split('-').map(function (value, index) {
            return parseInt(value, 16);
        });
        return String.fromCodePoint.apply(null, codes);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fchsrnqw/

Comment: mayeb you search for your real problem. `apply` of undefined means that the function `fromCodePoint` is not avaible in IE. Look at the Doc's, there is a nice polyfill too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint

Comment: i allready did a search for it last night, must have been tried as i could not get it to work, but it works now when i follow the docs on mozilla, thanks sysix!